# Parsing DateTime HHmmss

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, datetime

Well recently i was trying to parse this time 24:14:38 which MUST BE 12:14:38AM

so far this is my function

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string time)
{
    DateTime result;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(time, out result))
    {
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and here is how is it used

```
    var time = "24:14:38";
    var result = ParseDate(time.Replace(":", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

However i keep getting this error

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar
>   System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

SOLVED 24 Is not valid in 24 hour system, instead i should use 00:14:38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.  A time string with "24" as the hour value is not a valid time string.

Valid times have hour values from 1-12 for 12-hour time, or 0-23 for 24 hour time.

Comment: So how could be 12:14:38 be presented in HHmmss !

Comment: `12:14:38 AM` would be `00:14:38`